# Protege Export inferences does not work with rules

Tags: protege, swrl

I noticed in Protégé 5 that all the inferences obtained by SWRL rules
cannot be exported by using the "export inferred axioms as ontology" tool (with all the options enabled). For example, consider the following ontology:

```
`https://pastebin.com/ZCMgxzRs` .
```

The inference "a instaceOf B" is not exported as you can see from the results here:

```
 `https://pastebin.com/AaABJQt4` .
```

Is there any way to export such type of inferences?

Comment: I can't confirm. Coud you please post an example and describe your steps in the export wizard?

Comment: I have added a test case.

Comment: Have you checked `Class assertions (individual types)` in the wizard first step?

Comment: Yes, I've done with no result.

Comment: Strange... Which reasoner and which Protege version are you using? Does Protege show inferences in GUI  before exoorting?

Comment: I'm using pellet reasoner with protege 5.2.0 (same problem in the last beta). The inference is correctly shown in GUI, simply it is not exported.

Comment: Same problem with the last version of Hermit reasoner.

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems disappeared after a clean install of the tool.